# How to get information with 'request' library (python )from web page API?

Tags: python

The problem is that server status to my request answer 200 and its good, it means i have connection, but 'Content-Type': 'text/html' server:'nginx', how i can get information from this server ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend using bs4(beautiful soup)

Comment: Did you search in the doc? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-headers

Comment: Hello @AT, and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you post the link to the API you are using, and/or the returned content of the API (or an excerpt of it)? Please also post the code you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Those fields are available in the header.

```
r.headers['Content-Type']
r.headers['server']
```

Comment: yes, all information i have, my problem is to get information from this server, i mean all data, company provided identify names of data, but i see that this is not JSON, it's Javascript page with no any information.

Comment: That could be because the api isn't returning any json payload, otherwise you would get them in r.json()